# Let $G=\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ and $H=\{(a,b)\in\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}: 8\mid a+b\}$. What is the index $[G:H]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, index-notation

> Let $G=\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ and $H=\{(a,b)\in\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}: 8\mid a+b\}$. What is the index $[G:H]$?

From a separate exercise part of this problem we are given $H\lhd G$ and that $G/H\cong\mathbb{Z}_8.$

Considering the definition of $H$ I believe $|H|=8n$ (Since there are $8n$ entries that satisfy the condition).

How would I find $|G|$? Would this just be $\infty$?

Comment: Since $G=\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$, we have $\lvert G\rvert =\infty$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition, when we have $H\lhd G$ such that $G/H$ is finite, then $[G:H]:=|G/H|.$ In this case, then, $[G:H]=|\Bbb Z_8|=8.$

Comment: Thanks, but what happens to $|G|$? Since $H\lhd G$ does everything just go to $\mathbb{Z}_8$?

Comment: $|G|$ is infinite, and so is $|H|.$ If $G$ happened to be finite, then we can instead find $[G:H]$ by $|G|/|H|,$ but when $G$ is infinite, such a division doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately our notes on finding the index of subgroups were quite scant. In this scenario how would I demonstrate mathematically that the order is 8 aside from citing both groups are infinite?

Comment: You'd need to actually prove that $G/H$ has cardinality $8,$ but ideally, you should try to prove that $G/H\cong\Bbb Z_8.$ As a hint for how to do so, show that $$H=\bigl\{(a,8n-a):a,n\in\Bbb Z\bigr\},$$ and so $$H=\bigl\{a(1,-1)+n(0,8):a,n\in\Bbb Z\bigr\}.$$ From there, you should be able to show that the elements of $G/H$ are all of the form $(k,0)+H$ for some $k\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7\},$ that $(1,0)+H$ generates $G/H,$ and that $(1,0)+H$ has order $8.$

Comment: Thank you, I had that as the next step in the exercise grouping but didn't make the connection. This accelerated summer course runs off of lecture notes. Are you able to suggest a text for further study?

Comment: Michael Artin's book *Algebra* is what I learned this stuff from, personally.

Comment: Thanks, I'm pursuing further reading from Gallian and Stillwell per suggestion of my prof. I'll look into Artin, as well.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you already know that $G/H\cong\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$, then the index is $8$.

How can you *prove* the isomorphism? Just consider the obvious map
$$
\varphi\colon\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z},
\qquad
\varphi(a,b)=a+b+8\mathbb{Z}
$$
and prove it is a homomorphism. It is clearly surjective and its kernel is $H$. Thus the homomorphism theorem provides the required isomorphism.